# Play video from SAMBA share on Android--Any shared volume from Linux or Windows

Tags: linux, network-shares, android, video-streaming, smb

I use Ubuntu12.10 with Gnomeshell.

Installed latest version of samba share, configured to share my Video folder, access restricted via login (uid and password needed).

SMB share accessed via Solid explorer when I tried to open the video file (size 600MB, type MKV) the player used BS Player MX Player were not able to play the file.. it says buffering and stops...

Any one has a solution to play video from Shared drive on Android?

Comment: From any share can be used, I am referring Samba sharing as an example

Comment: I use File Manager HD by Rhythm Software. It works flawlessly with VLC for Android and MX Player. I'd recommend that file manager instead as it actually streams the file to the device rather than actually downloading it to the device.

Comment: I will give it a try will let you know..  Thanks for the replay..

Comment: It helped... its working.. better than any other file browser

Comment: Awesome, I'll post the solution as a proper answer! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative app you can use on android is File Manager HD by Rhythm Software (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm.hd&hl=en). I find that it does a better job of actual streaming rather than other alternatives downloading the file to your device.

On Android 4.2, it is working streaming over SMB to VLC for Android ([https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy52aWRlb2xhbi52bGMuYmV0YXY3bmVvbiJd)) and MX Player ([https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5teHRlY2gudmlkZW9wbGF5ZXIuYWQiXQ../)).

You should be able to see all shared files over SMB so long as you set the connection up properly in File Manager HD.

Comment: I was able to play the file.. which was not possible with others.. the play quality depend on the connection speed/the users connected to the router( smaller the better )

Comment: I just found a VLC beta thing, which couldn't fast forward or skip back, etc. MX Player worked.

Comment: @AjoMathew Do you mean stutter? -- The video file on the server does not change, no matter the connection! If it's not enough bandwidth, it will stutter or buffer all too often.

Answer (score 4):

ES File explorer also solves this and prompts for which app to use if the file type is unknown. Hence ES File explorer is a better solution.

If you are interested, I am using ES File Explorer to connect to an old MS Media Center 2005 (MCE). The files are encoded using an MS variant of MPG with an extension of .dvr-ms  MX Player does a great job of playing these files with no errors

Answer (score 3):

[Kodi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kodi) (previously called XBMC) has an Android port with SMB support.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the 
[File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager&hl=en) from Flashlight + Clock.

It is free, add free and starts playing immediately without download the file before.